# Get Major and Minor from UUID of Estimote iBeacon

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uuid, ibeacon

I just got my pack of Estimote iBeacons and I am trying to do something that sounds like it would be pretty simple.

I would like to get the "major" and "minor" id from the beacon that triggered the didEnterRegion method. The method is below:

```
-(void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
      didEnterRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = @"Welcome home rockstar!";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

I know that the UUID for an Estimote beacon is always B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D. But how would I get the major and minor id from the particular beacon that trigerred this event? I would like to have the two ids formatted as NSStrings.

Any assistance would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Hi how to connect Estimote Beacons to data base and how to fetch the data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to get the major and minor.  Simply combine ranging and monitoring together.  Detailed instructions are available in my answer to this question:
[iBeacon: get major and minor - only looking for uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124443/ibeacon-get-major-and-minor-only-looking-for-uuid)

Answer (score 2):

[According to the `ESTBeaconRegion.h` file](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/blob/master/EstimoteSDK/Headers/ESTBeaconRegion.h), an `ESTBeaconRegion` is a subclass of [`CLBeaconRegion`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeaconRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html) which has a `major` `NSNumber *` property and a `minor` `NSNumber *` property.

So you should just be able to do:

```
- (void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region {
    NSNumber *major = region.major;
    NSNumber *minor = region.minor;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in the example:  [Estimote / iOS-SDK / ProximityDemo](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/tree/master/ProximityDemo/ProximityDemo)

It looks like you need to:
Instantiate

```
ESTBeaconManager
```

then

```
startRangingBeaconsInRegion
```

In the delegate method:

```
-(void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
     didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
            inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region
```

Get the array of beacons and for each beacon:

```
ibeacon.major
ibeacon.minor
```

Answer (score 1):

Estimote's beacon and beacon region classes are based on Apple's classes, and (I assume) work the same way) In the work I've done I've ignored their classes and used CLBeacon and CLBeaconRegion.

Assuming Estimote's classes work the same way as Apple's if you set up a beacon region with no major and minor version number, then any beacon with the matching UUID triggers enteredRegion and exitRegion notices, but the major and minor values are blank in the notification. You don't get the major and minor values of the beacons that triggered the event unless you ask for and receive ranging calls.

If instead you create a beacon region with a major value or a major and minor value, you only get notifications for beacons that match those values. In those cases, the region object you get will include the major or major/minor value you specified when you created the region, but those values will not change.