# CLLocationManager didEnterRegion: with iBeacon while app is suspended

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm trying to wake up my app (relaunch it) when it enters my defined beacon region but I just can't get it to work. This are the steps and code I'm using.

1. Set "Location updates" Background Mode to YES.
2. Monitor my CLBeaconRegion

   ```
   NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"EBEFD083-70A2-47C8-9837-E7B5634DF524"];
       beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"daRegion"];
       beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = NO;
       beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
       beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
       self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
       self.locationManager.delegate = self;
       [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
   ```
3. Implement delegate methods

   ```
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
   ```

Anything that I might be missing? I have read the documentation, blog posts, forums and nothing seems to work. [This](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html) is one of the websites I read, and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) is the other.

Comment: Does your app detect the beacons in the foreground?

Comment: Yes it does, even in background, I just can't get it working when the app is killed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comment "I just can't get it working when the app is killed" is critical.

If you use the iOS7 app switcher to kill an app (e.g. by swiping up on the app icon), then you will not be able to re-launch the app in the background upon entering or leaving an iBeacon region.  This is by design -- if the user doesn't want the app running, then Apple thinks code should not be able to make it re-launch.  [See this thread.](https://devforums.apple.com/message/886796#886796)

Fortunately, users don't typically do this.  For testing purposes, if you want to completely stop an app, don't do this.  Reboot your phone instead.  (Note, however, that it takes a minute or so after boot before you can detect iBeacons.)

**EDIT 2014/03/10:  This behavior has changed as of the release of iOS 7.1.  Killing an app from the task switcher no longer stops it from detecting iBeacons in the background.**

Comment: No ofense but I think (80% sure) you're kind of wrong and Apple docs say the opposite here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW7
I'm a fan of your work and your blog post, maybe you're right and Apple got it wrong in the part they mention you can monitor a region and still get delegate callbacks even if your app is not running.
Thanks for the response anyways.

Comment: @herz, I would love to be wrong!  I disagree that these two documents are inconsistent.  The one you reference says a callback will be made "even if you app is not running."  This is true, but it leaves out the detail that the app must have been run at least once for this to work.  Killing an app from the app switcher essentially puts your app back to the state before it was ever launched the first time.  If you doubt this, it is pretty easy to set up a test and try yourself.  I would love to hear your results!

Comment: Oh well, maybe the part of "even if your app is not running" is not clear enough ... Then I think I've got it working with the app still in the switcher being inactive, thanks for the clarification then. Another easy way to go to an inactive state instead of rebooting the phone is just running the app in Xcode and then stop it, faster and easier.

Comment: I'll accept your answer because of your clarification and your whole help with this beacon topic, thanks again!