# How to find number of devices is in iBeacon range?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

Currently I'm following this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/ios7-programming-ibeacons-tutorial/.

And created one broadcasting beacon. Other devices will detect this beacon when these users enter the region. What I want to know is who are the customers in the mall right now. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understand that bluetooth beacons are one way transmitters.  They have no knowledge of what devices, if any, detected them.

If you have an app on each of the devices that detected the beacon, you can program something into the app that reports to a server when it saw the beacon.  Using this technique, you can calculate on.the server how many mobile devices saw the beacon  in a given time frame.

Answer (score 0):

If your iBeacon transmitter is an iOS device such as an iPhone or iPad, you can set it to transmit and receive at the same time. If you're using a dedicated iBeacon device like Estimote, they are transmit only and will not be aware of how many clients are nearby.

Further discussion on simultaneous transmission/reception can be found here: [iBeacon app - receiving/transmitting at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272249/ibeacon-app-receiving-transmitting-at-the-same-time)